# how to get pointer member in structer in C?

Tags: c

below first the code block works while I'm getting the type of char pointer. But for the second code block, when I try to get the type of inter pointer, it doesn't work. Please someone explain to me, why it is not working to get integer pointer? Thank you..

```
// FIRST CODE BLOCK

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    struct machine
    {
        char *memory;   
    };

    struct machine CPUtype;

    struct machine *mpu641;

    CPUtype.memory="QWERTY";
    mpu641=&CPUtype;

    printf("The value i %s\n",mpu641->memory);

    return 0;
}

// SECOND CODE BLOCK

int main()
{
    struct machine
    {
        int *memory;    
    };

    struct machine CPUtype;

    struct machine *mpu641;

    CPUtype.memory=5;
    mpu641=&CPUtype;

    printf("The value i %d\n",mpu641->memory);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. "Does not work" is not a useful problem description. If something does not compile, you will get an error message.

Comment: Please edit the question to remove the `enter code here` bits.  And fix 'structure' in the title.

Comment: In the first code, you made the point somewhere sane.  The second block should have gotten lots of warnings from the compiler and a crash at runtime because the pointer doesn't point anywhere sane.  Address 5 is not sane!

Comment: Go to learn more about pointers first. If you like technical writing: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/pointer

Answer (score 1):

You try to assign an integer to a pointer variable. That does not work.

First code:

```
CPUtype.memory="QWERTY";
```

This is fine, because `"QWERTY"` is a string literal and the address of the first character is assigned to your `char*` member.

Seconde code:

```
CPUtype.memory=5;
```

Here you try to assign an integer to a pointer variable. Therefore you will get some messages from your compiler.
Try to assign an address and it should work fine.

How you should do this, depends on the rest of your program.
You have various options:

```
// assign address of some variable
int intvar;
mpu641->memory = &intvar;

// dynamic memory allocations
CPUtype.memory = malloc(sizeof(int));

// fixed address of some registers etc.
// Requires cast and is not portable
CPUtype.memory = (int *) 0x100000
```

Also printing is wrong:

```
printf("The value i %d\n",mpu641->memory);
```

You try to print an integer but pass a pointer to integer. To get the value pointed to, you need to use this:

```
printf("The value i %d\n", *(mpu641->memory));
```

Comment: That first assignment is legal, but it's only borderline "fine", because a string literal is a const object, and any attempt to modify it through the non-const pointer is UB.  A good compiler will warn about such assignments.

Comment: @TobySpeight True, but in the given code no write accesses are done using the pointer. Also in C string literals are not of const type as they are in C++. Therefore technically the assignment to a non const pointer is OK.